# How to look-up constraint by number in a Pyomo model?

Tags: pyomo

We are attempted to debug a Pyomo model. Ipopt with `halt_on_ampl_error` `True` tells up `Error evaluating constraint 30`. Is there an easy way to programmatically look up a constraint in a Pyomo model by its number (using the numbering of Ipopt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just modify your call to solve slightly:

```
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
res = opt.solve(model, symbolic_solver_labels=True)
```

Then, you should see a more useful error message in the ipopt output.

Let me extend this answer to address the other part of the question regarding looking up a constraint by its number. Because Pyomo variables and constraints do not have indices, this is very solver-interface-specific. For Pynumero, you have a couple of options. Suppose you have the following `ConcreteModel` called `m` and `PyomoNLP` called `nlp`.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.contrib.pynumero.interfaces.pyomo_nlp import PyomoNLP

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.x = pyo.Var()
m.y = pyo.Var()
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=m.y)
m.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.y >= m.x)
m.c2 = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.y >= -m.x)

nlp = PyomoNLP(m)
```

If you just want to get the index of of a few variables or constraints, you can use

```py
var_indices = nlp.get_primal_indices([m.x, m.y])
con_indices = nlp.get_constraint_indices([m.c1, m.c2])
```

If you want complete maps both directions, you can use

```py
con_to_index = dict()
index_to_con = dict()
var_to_index = pyo.ComponentMap()
index_to-var = dict()
for ndx, var in enumerate(nlp.get_pyomo_variables()):
    var_to_index[var] = ndx
    index_to_var[ndx] = var
for ndx, con in enumerate(nlp.get_pyomo_constraints()):
    con_to_index[con] = ndx
    index_to_con[ndx] = con
```

Comment: This solution works for the immediate Ipopt use case. But if I calculate the Jacobian with Pynumero, I believe the equation and variable numbers are stripped out. I would like to know which variable and equation correspond to say, the 3rd row and 2nd column of the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using the PyomoNLP interface in PyNumero. If you are using the asl interface, this is a little more difficult. With the PyomoNLP interface in PyNumero, there are several methods that should be able to do what you need. Have a look at the comments in pyomo_nlp.py. Note that this stuff is pretty new and the API is subject to change.